# AJAX vs PHP submit of form

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I originally had a form set up as such (CSS styles have been removed)

```
<form name="LoginForm" action="login.php" method="post">

<input name="email" id="email" type="text"></input>

<input name="password" id="password" type="password"></input>

<input name="login" id="login" type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
```

and it worked fine, and login.php would validate the user creditionals. However, that approach required a page redirect. I am trying to migrate the code to AJAX so I can query the login details and stay within the page. [edit] here is the AJAX object I use

```
function Ajax(){
    this.xmlhttp=null;  //code below will assign correct request object
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        this.xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{       // code for IE6, IE5
        this.xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    this.stateChangeFunction=function(){};  //user must reimplement this

    var that=this;
    this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ //executes the appropriate code when the ready state and status are correct
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
            that.stateChangeFunction();     
        }
        else{
            dump("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

then I have a login.js function, which I am not too sure how to incorporate, currently I add it to the onclick event of the submit button:

```
function login(email,password){
    var ajax=new Ajax();

    //ajax.xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?LoginEmailField="+email+",LoginPasswordField="+password,true);
    //ajax.xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You will notice how those last two lines are commented out, I am not too sure how to send arguments at the moment, but the point is that even with the two commented out, the entire site still reloads. What is the correct way to use AJAX in forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I havent done enough ajax in raw js to give a tutorial here so Im' going to use jquery. However anything i show can be done in raw javascript so maybe someone else will be kind enough to show you a raw implementation.

First of all you should use POST instead of GET for your login. Secondly as i said in my comment you should use the actual URL to the login page as the action. This way users who dont have JS for whatever reason can still login. Its best to do this by binding to the forms `onSubmit` event.

```
<form name="LoginForm" action="login.php" method="post">

<input name="email" id="email" type="text"></input>

<input name="password" id="password" type="password"></input>

<input name="login" id="login" type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
```

And with jquery:

```
function doLogin(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from doing its normal post
  var form = $('form[name=LoginForm]');
  // post via ajax instead
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'), // grab the value of the action attribute "login.php"
    data: form.serialize(), // converts input fields to a query string
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){
      /* callback when status is 200
       * you can redirect here ... data is the response from the server, 
       * send the redirect URL in this response
       */
      window.location.href = data;
    },
    error: function(textStatus){
      alert('ERROR');
    }
  });
}

// bind our function to the onSubmit event of the form
$('form[name=LoginForm]').submit(doLogin);
```

Then on the serverside you can check if its an ajax based request:

```
<?php

 // do your login stuff

 // set $successUrl to the URL you want to redirect to

 // check if its ajax
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
   && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
 {
   echo $successUrl;
   exit(0);
 }
 else
 {
    // was a non-ajax request - do a normal redirect
    header('Location: '.$successUrl);
 }
```

Comment: That looks very complicated, here is the approach I am currently taking. I changed the form header to `<form name="LoginForm">` and then changed the submit button to a normal button as so `<input name="button" id="button" type="button" onclick="login();" value="Login"></input>` then in login() I manually extract the other input fields

Comment: youre essentially doing the same thing i just wrote code for except that by using a non-submit input and removing the `action` from the form you are not allowing users who dont have javascript enabled to login... Additionally since youre using get instead of post youre allowing anyone to just type random usernames and passwords into the browser to login... At least with post its a bit more of hassle, though you should be using some kind of CSRF token validation...

Comment: I see why get could have that problem, but wouldn't it only really be a problem if it was continually updated on every keystroke?

Comment: Im not sure what youre getting at.. key strokes have nothing to do with it.. im talking about entering the URL directly into the location bar of the browser or using CURL in a script to run an attack... granted even with POST unless you have some kind of verification system to ensure the request is in response to your form i can still do the same thing using a scripted solution... but thats neither here nor there at the moment.

Comment: I see what you mean, I never thought of it because I guess I just thought I'd "cross that bridge when I came to it". Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code only shows `HTML`. `AJAX` uses `javascript` to communicate to PHP script.

So, Only on seeing the `js` code, Debugging is possible.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the default event you have to use `action='javascript: void(null);'` instead of removing it.

Comment: I inserted the `action='javascript: void(null);'` statement and it did indeed prevent the reload. Now, would you happen to know how to correctly redirect on submit to a javascript function? Should I insert it in place of `void(null)` (didn't work for me), or should I add it to the onclick event of the submit button? Thanks

Comment: Using that as the action makes it impossible for non-js enabled users to login. you should really just bind to the `onSubmit` event of the `form` and then grab the URL from the action.

Comment: @prodigitalson: I don't fully understand. grab what URL? Do you mean somthing like this: `<form name="x" action='javascript: void(null);' method="post" onSubmit='load();'>`

Comment: @puk: I use to work with AJAX using jQuery. What I do is to use `$.post` or `$.get` functions after a short validation in javascript. The validation is `onSubmit` event.

Comment: @puk: see my answer for some more detail... albeit with jquery instead of raw js. Essentially instead of binding to the buttons `onClick` you bind to the form's `onSubmit` which will be triggered by the click...